# Xubuntu 12.04 LTS installed in vbox

Tags: virtualbox, xubuntu, update-manager

When I run update manager, it shows updates of 212mb, but does not download or install them.
ditto, when I run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

it shows all the available updates, but does not install.

Comment: Please [add](http://askubuntu.com/posts/294038/edit) the errors you get when running `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` in a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

To upgrade packages with bugfixes in a terminal we need to perfom at least two steps:

- update the (apt) cache for packages

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  ```
- upgrade packages

  ```
  sudo apt-get upgrade
  ```
- extended upgrades and removal of packages including kernel upgrades (as done with update manager)

  ```
  sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
  ```

We can also combine those commands in a single line to perform similar to the update manager:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Watch out for unwanted package removals before you accept with `Y`.